# requiring using /var/www works but using localhost doesnt work

Tags: php, linux

I am new to working on linux environment and i am also working on a php project on linux. And I faced a problem while requiring php files. I have two php files called test.php and database.php. Both this files are in /var/www/TEST/.

This the code in database.php

`<?php echo("You have included the database");  ?>`

And this is the code in test.php

```
<?php require("/var/www/TEST/database.php");?>
```

Then when i browse to test.php using firefox i get the expected output "you have included the database". but when I change test.php to

```
<?php require("localhost/TEST/database.php"); ?>
```

I get no out put when I browse to test.php. I have started the apache service and also changed the file access of /var/www/ to 755. I hope you could help me on why I am getting this kind of result. Thank you.

Comment: you should simply use `require('database.php')`;

Comment: Try adding `http://` before localhost.

Comment: I think that you are confusing what URLs and what paths are. Those are two different concepts (you might change your domain to example.com but keep the same path). I am sure you can find details on these things. An answer I gave some time ago on a similar matter can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10913412/521598

Comment: @sagarGuhe I know that it works using your way, But since i wanted to create a static reference to other files to the database.php i wanted to access it through a localhost or the ip address of my computer(i wanted it to be accessd from other  computers too).

Answer (score 1):

First you should enable error reporting:

```
<?php 
// Put these lines to the top of your script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
ini_set('xmlrpc_errors', true);
```

Then you try to include a file via HTTP stream, but you forgot `http://` or `https://` before  `localhost` **and** including via stream is  **disabled** for security reason.
The configuration is `allow_url_include`. It's off by default and you should leave it off.

Try to get into composer / psr classmaps / psr autoloading. This is kinda "industry standard" mechanism. You should go for that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To make it as a static reference you can code it like:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/TEST/database.php'); // $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gets you '/var/www' or whatever your server root maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require("database.php");?>

<?php require("database.php"); ?>
```

No Need To require Full Path When You Are Working in One Folder