# PHP how to check if image url is false

Tags: php

How can I check if a url directs to an image file, and 
http://website.com/images-stories/gallery/image-name.jpg

and if there is no file in the location, default to another url (for a default file).

I was using file_exists but realize that checks a path not a url.

```
<?PHP
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

    $smaller_img = $data['smaller_img'];


    $url = $smaller_img;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode=200) 
{
$smaller_imgf=$url;
} else {
$smaller_imgf='../images/submit_icon.png';
}  
    ?>

<img src="<?php echo $smaller_imgf; ?>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: You should use `cURL` in addition to checking returning header

Comment: Looks a lot like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722613/check-if-a-remote-page-exists-using-php

Comment: Agree with Stefan, but there's loads of dupes of this.

Comment: `get_headers($url, 1)` with `stream_context` set to only `HEAD` or - `curl` with fetch headers only

Comment: you can check it with exif_imagetype(); function.

    if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
        echo 'This is not gif.';
    }

[Click Here For More Information][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.exif-imagetype.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look with `curl` for status code `200`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797723/2441442

If 200, you can check for image with `getimagesize`

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Thank you @christian golhardt. I posted my current script and I'm having an issue, I have a feeling I'm doing something incorrectly when defining $httpcode

Comment: `($httpcode=200)` should be `($httpcode==200)` ;)

Comment: @buzrw I recommend you a good IDE such as `PHP Storm`. It will warn you, if you make a mistake and have unreachable code :)